# How to get all amazon products of any given browsenodeid

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I want to get maximum number of products for any specified browsenodeid. I am trying this by executing operation in loop and increase ItemPage by 1. Here is my code:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++):
    $sin = array(
      "Operation"     => "ItemSearch",
      "SearchIndex"   => $cat_name,
      "BrowseNode"    => $browse_node_id,
      "ItemPage"      => $i,
      "Condition"     => "All",
      "ResponseGroup" => "Medium, Reviews, OfferFull",
      "MerchantId"    => "Amazon"       
    );
 endfor;
```

But if i run this till 11 in while loop, it does not return any result for pages more than 10 . But on Amazon it is showing results on 400 pages.

Answer (score 2):

The API will not return more than 10 result pages for any search. One way of getting more results is to set MinimumPrice and MaximumPrice so that you get 10 or fewer pages and then adjust the range and repeat.